# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} [IPv4] prevent catch IP range?

Tags: .htaccess

A RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} with a IPv4 catch a IP range. Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.89
# catch 123.45.67.89
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.8
# catch 123.45.67.8[0-9]

# or as omit
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89
...
```

Eventually catch it more. I have no further tested. My actuall IP is (similar to the example) "123.45.67.89".

The RewriteCond is for a RewriteRule to rewrite temporary to a maintenance.php. I insert my IP. Only my IP don't rewrite to maintenance.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule . maintenance.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.89
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

With use this with IP 123.45.67.89, i becomes the index.php. With use this with IP 123.45.67.8, i becomes the index.php. With use this with IP 123.45.67.890, i becomes the maintenance.php. How can i prevent to catch / omit more than my IP adress? Besides, i have dynamic IP adress. It's possible my IP is 123.45.67.8.

EDIT: thanks to @anubhava.
Solution: `^123\.45\.67\.89$`

Comment: please read my edit. @anubhava, for what is the "d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My actuall IP is (similar to) `123.45.67.89`. How can i prevent to catch / omit more than my IP address? Besides, i have dynamic IP address. It's possible my IP is `123.45.67.8`

if you want to match only single IP then you will have to hardcode that IP by using

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
```

Note that you need to escape dots in your IP address to avoid it matching any character.

Your rules can be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hm, my question was: ONLY match one/my IP. "any IP that starts with" isn't a solution. or?

Comment: Ha! That was my idea on this moment! Trailing "$" solves! Thanks for all!

Comment: that was a missunderstand with the dynamic IP. it was only a another example IP. On every time only ONE IP are catch/match/omit.

Comment: Why only one RewriteCond?

Comment: certainly? there is a [L] (last).

Comment: OK. i have tested it. it works. but i dont understand it, because, i have more conds and rules. i will open a new question.

Comment: Hm, or not new question. The thing with the maintenance is only temporary. The second Rule is forever. But, when i commend out the Cond and first Rule, the second Rule are without Cond, or associated with the previous Cond and Rule. Please a solution for commend out the temporary maintenance Cond & Rule.

Comment: Think: i must have 1 Rule with maintenance and 2 Rules with index (the first for commend out), and then i commend out toggle the first 2 Rules?

Comment: That isn't a solution. because, the last Rule with index.php is common for SEO URLs, and must work allways for all IPs in abcense of maintenance.

Comment: sorry then it is better if you post a new question. Let's not extend this already long comment section.